# How can you use hooks in different components in React Native and have them show the same values?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, components, state

I am using hooks to set and change a value inside two different components. When I update the value in one of the components, it is not updated in the other, and if navigate out of the component and then back the value is reset. The code for the first component is below:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import useWord from '../hooks/useWord';

const TextComponent = () => {
  const [changeWord, word, errorMessage] = useWord();
  const [text, onChangeText] = useState('');

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Text Component</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={text}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
      />
      <Button title={'Add text'} onPress={() => changeWord(text)} />
      {errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
      <Text>{word}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default TextComponent;
```

The code for the second component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import useWord from '../hooks/useWord';

const OverviewComponent = props => {
  const [changeWord, word, errorMessage] = useWord();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Overview Component</Text>

      <Button
        title={'Go to text demo'}
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Text')}
      />
      {errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
      <Text>{word}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default OverviewComponent;
```

The code for the hook is:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [word, setWord] = useState(['B']);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const changeWord = async letter => {
    console.log('Hi there');
    try {
      setWord([...word, letter]);
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage('Something went wrong');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    changeWord('B');
  }, []);

  return [changeWord, word, errorMessage];
};
```

How can I update the value inside one of the components and then navigate to the other component and see the updated value?

Comment: hooks like components do not store state outside of their existence.  Each time you use your hook, its a new instance.  For both components to share the same state you would have to **lift up state** (simply means you would have to save both their states in a parent component) or you can use something like context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: try putting `useWord` in the parent object of these components and passing down just the values as properties

Comment: Better to use context, redux, reducer or wrap them in component that handle shared values, what you did I think is to make different setWord hook for each component so the value is different in each component, each setWord point to different component

Answer (score 1):

The thing with react hooks is they do not store state or values outside of the component's existence, in which they are used. The best solution can be you provide the state of a parent component and send it via props to the children components and use the state there. React hooks have a new instance each time you use them.